# python How to use eval with lambda

Tags: python, lambda, pyqt, pyqt5, eval

Is there a way that I can use eval with lambda?Because I tried to do it but I just got an error which was **Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'self' is not defined**
and this is my code:

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("main.db")
cu = connection.cursor()
count = 1
cc = 100
xx = 1
countFrame = 11
class mainapp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainapp, self).__init__()
        loadUi("main.ui", self)
        global xx
        self.pages.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.goList.clicked.connect(self.goToList)
        if xx == 1:
            self.gridLayout_99 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frameShow)
            self.gridLayout_99.setObjectName("gridLayout_99")
            xx = 0
    def goToList(self):
        global count , cc
        self.pages.setCurrentIndex(2)
        self.check()
    def check(self):
        global count , cc , countFrame
        if count != 1:
            for i in range(self.gridLayout_99.count()):
                try:
                    item = self.gridLayout_99.itemAt(i).widget()
                    item.setParent(None)
                except:
                    print("Bruh")
                    
            
            cu.execute("SELECT * FROM data")
            self.all_buttons = []
            push_style = """
            QPushButton{
    background-color:transparent;
    border : 3px solid rgb(0, 74, 255);
    border-radius : 15px;
        color: rgb(215, 222, 218);
        font: 75 italic 15pt "Arial";
    }
            """
            x = 0
            y = 0

            vcount = 100
            hcount = 100
            for row in cu.fetchall():
                exec("self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+" = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frameShow)")
                eval("self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+".setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 120, 231, 241))")
                eval("self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+".setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(231, 241))")
                eval("self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+".setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(231, 241))")
                eval("""self.frame_"""+str(countFrame)+""".setStyleSheet('''\n
        QFrame{\n
        background-color:transparent;\n
        border : 3px solid rgb(0, 74, 255);\n
        border-radius : 15px;\n
           color: rgb(215, 222, 218);\n
            font: 75 italic 15pt \"Arial\";\n
        }''')""")
                eval("self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+".setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)")
                eval("self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+".setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)")
                eval("self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+".setObjectName('frame_"+str(countFrame)+"')")
                exec("self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+")")
                self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
                exec("self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+")")
                print(eval("self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+""))
                self.label_7.setText(row[0])
                self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
                self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_7)
                self.horizontalLayout_10 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
                self.horizontalLayout_10.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_10")
                exec("self.frame_12 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+")")
                self.frame_12.setStyleSheet("border-color: transparent;")
                self.frame_12.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
                self.frame_12.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
                self.frame_12.setObjectName("frame_12")
                self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.frame_12)
                self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
                self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
                self.horizontalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
                self.horizontalLayout_9.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_9")
                exec("self.frame_15 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+")")
                self.frame_15.setStyleSheet("border-color: transparent;")
                self.frame_15.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
                self.frame_15.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
                self.frame_15.setObjectName("frame_15")
                self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.frame_15)
                exec("self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+")")
                sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
                sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
                sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
                sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
                self.pushButton_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
                self.pushButton_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
                self.pushButton_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 16777215))
                self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color : transparent;\n"
        "border : 3px solid rgb(163, 163, 163) ;\n"
        "border-radius : 15px;\n"
        "color: rgb(163, 163, 163);\n"
        "font: 75 17pt \"Arial\";")
                icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
                icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("eye-3-256.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
                self.pushButton_4.setIcon(icon2)
                self.pushButton_4.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
                self.pushButton_4.setDefault(False)
                self.pushButton_4.setFlat(False)
                self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
                self.pushButton_4.setText("view")
                self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(lambda ignored , value=row[0]: self.view_it(value))
                self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
                exec("self.frame_16 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+")")
                self.frame_16.setStyleSheet("border-color: transparent;")
                self.frame_16.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
                self.frame_16.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
                self.frame_16.setObjectName("frame_16")
                self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.frame_16)
                self.verticalLayout_6.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_9)
                exec("self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+" = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+")")
                eval("self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+".setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 50))")
                eval("self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+".setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 50))")
                eval("""self.pushButton_"""+str(countFrame)+""".setStyleSheet('''background-color : transparent;\n
        border : 3px solid rgb(255, 0, 0) ;\n
        border-radius : 15px;\n
        color: red;\n
        font: 75 17pt \"Arial\";\n
        ''')""")
                icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
                icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("trash-4-256(1).png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
                eval("self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+".setIcon(icon3)")
                eval("self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+".setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))")
                eval("self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+".setObjectName('pushButton_3')")
                eval("self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+".setText('delete')")
                eval("self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+".clicked.connect(lambda value=self.label_7.text() , number=countFrame: self.delete_it(value , number))")
                eval("self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+", 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)")
                self.horizontalLayout_10.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_6)
                exec("self.frame_14 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+")")
                self.frame_14.setStyleSheet("border-color: transparent;")
                self.frame_14.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
                self.frame_14.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
                self.frame_14.setObjectName("frame_14")
                self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.frame_14)
                self.verticalLayout_7.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_10)
                self.pushButton_4.raise_()
                self.label_7.raise_()
                self.frame_12.raise_()
                self.frame_14.raise_()
                # self.pushButton_3.raise_()
                self.frame_15.raise_()
                self.frame_16.raise_()
                self.gridLayout_99.addWidget(self.frame_11, x, y, 1, 1)
                count +=1
                y += 1
                if y > 2:
                    y = 0
                    x += 1
                else:
                    pass
            countFrame += 1
            count += 1
            countFrame = 11
        else:
            
            self.pages.setCurrentIndex(2)
            cu.execute("SELECT * FROM data")
            self.all_buttons = []
            push_style = """
            QPushButton{
    background-color:transparent;
    border : 3px solid rgb(0, 74, 255);
    border-radius : 15px;
        color: rgb(215, 222, 218);
        font: 75 italic 15pt "Arial";
    }
            """
            x = 0
            y = 0
            vcount = 100
            hcount = 100
            for row in cu.fetchall():
                exec("self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+" = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frameShow)")
                eval("self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+".setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 120, 231, 241))")
                eval("self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+".setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(231, 241))")
                eval("self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+".setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(231, 241))")
                eval("""self.frame_"""+str(countFrame)+""".setStyleSheet('''\n
        QFrame{\n
        background-color:transparent;\n
        border : 3px solid rgb(0, 74, 255);\n
        border-radius : 15px;\n
           color: rgb(215, 222, 218);\n
            font: 75 italic 15pt \"Arial\";\n
        }''')""")
                eval("self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+".setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)")
                eval("self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+".setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)")
                eval("self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+".setObjectName('frame_"+str(countFrame)+"')")
                exec("self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+")")
                self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
                exec("self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+")")
                print(eval("self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+""))
                self.label_7.setText(row[0])
                self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
                self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_7)
                self.horizontalLayout_10 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
                self.horizontalLayout_10.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_10")
                exec("self.frame_12 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+")")
                self.frame_12.setStyleSheet("border-color: transparent;")
                self.frame_12.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
                self.frame_12.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
                self.frame_12.setObjectName("frame_12")
                self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.frame_12)
                self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
                self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
                self.horizontalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
                self.horizontalLayout_9.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_9")
                exec("self.frame_15 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+")")
                self.frame_15.setStyleSheet("border-color: transparent;")
                self.frame_15.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
                self.frame_15.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
                self.frame_15.setObjectName("frame_15")
                self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.frame_15)
                exec("self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+")")
                sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
                sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
                sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
                sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
                self.pushButton_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
                self.pushButton_4.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 50))
                self.pushButton_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 16777215))
                self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color : transparent;\n"
        "border : 3px solid rgb(163, 163, 163) ;\n"
        "border-radius : 15px;\n"
        "color: rgb(163, 163, 163);\n"
        "font: 75 17pt \"Arial\";")
                icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
                icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("eye-3-256.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
                self.pushButton_4.setIcon(icon2)
                self.pushButton_4.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
                self.pushButton_4.setDefault(False)
                self.pushButton_4.setFlat(False)
                self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
                self.pushButton_4.setText("view")
                self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(lambda ignored , value=row[0]: self.view_it(value))
                self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
                exec("self.frame_16 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+")")
                self.frame_16.setStyleSheet("border-color: transparent;")
                self.frame_16.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
                self.frame_16.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
                self.frame_16.setObjectName("frame_16")
                self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.frame_16)
                self.verticalLayout_6.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_9)
                exec("self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+" = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+")")
                eval("self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+".setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 50))")
                eval("self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+".setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(140, 50))")
                eval("""self.pushButton_"""+str(countFrame)+""".setStyleSheet('''background-color : transparent;\n
        border : 3px solid rgb(255, 0, 0) ;\n
        border-radius : 15px;\n
        color: red;\n
        font: 75 17pt \"Arial\";\n
        ''')""")
                icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
                icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("trash-4-256(1).png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
                eval("self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+".setIcon(icon3)")
                eval("self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+".setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))")
                eval("self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+".setObjectName('pushButton_3')")
                eval("self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+".setText('delete')")
                eval("self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+".clicked.connect(lambda value=self.label_7.text() , number=countFrame: self.delete_it(value , number))")
                eval("self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.pushButton_"+str(countFrame)+", 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)")
                self.horizontalLayout_10.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_6)
                exec("self.frame_14 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_"+str(countFrame)+")")
                self.frame_14.setStyleSheet("border-color: transparent;")
                self.frame_14.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
                self.frame_14.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
                self.frame_14.setObjectName("frame_14")
                self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.frame_14)
                self.verticalLayout_7.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_10)
                self.pushButton_4.raise_()
                self.label_7.raise_()
                self.frame_12.raise_()
                self.frame_14.raise_()
                # self.pushButton_3.raise_()
                self.frame_15.raise_()
                self.frame_16.raise_()
                self.gridLayout_99.addWidget(self.frame_11, x, y, 1, 1) 
                count +=1
                y += 1
                if y > 2:
                    y = 0
                    x += 1
                else:
                    pass
            countFrame += 1
            count += 1
        countFrame = 11
    def delete_it(self , name , num):
        
        # cu.execute(f"DELETE FROM data WHERE title = '{name}'")
        # connection.commit()
        cu.execute("SELECT * FROM data")
        datas = cu.fetchall()
        print(datas)
        new_num = num-11
        print(num)
        print(datas[new_num])
        # print(name)
    



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
myApp = mainapp()
myApp.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I also tried my code without eval but it returned **False** after I printed name in the delete_it function

Comment: Don't do this.  What you've done there is horrible coding practice, and `eval` is quite dangerous.  If you have multiple frames, store them in a list and use list indexing.

Comment: Alternatively, use [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) (but for dynamically created objects like these it's usually unnecessary, and using data structures like lists or dictionaries is usually better). Also, don't use globals. But, no, seriously, don't use `eval()`.